# Проблема импорта библиотек при запуске из другого файла в потоке

Tags: python, многопоточность, импорт, threading

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]есть файл starter.py с таким содержимым

```
import os
import threading


def run_test1():
    os.system('python test1.py')


def run_test2():
    os.system('python test2.py')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run_test1)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=run_test2)

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

по отдельности файлы test1.py и test2.py запускаются отлично, но когда я хочу запустить их через файл стартера в 2 потоках, получаю ошибку импорта в каждом:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\1\2\3\test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lib1 import lib1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\1\2\3\test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from lib2 import lib2 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib2'
```

названия библиотек для примера. Используется виртуальное окружение

Comment: А где расположены `lib1` и `lib2` - на том же уровне, где и `test1` и `test2`? А текущий каталог именно тот, где они расположены, или вы запускаете скрипт, указав к нему полный путь, а текущий каталог при этом бог знает какой? Импорт работает относительно текущего каталога по идее.

Comment: Я добавила скриншот с директориями, все библиотеки установлены в venv

Comment: По сути os.system('python test2.py') я запускаю обычным пайтоном а не виртуальным окружением файл, как тогда указать интерпретатор именно венв

Comment: А вот найти, где интерпретатор лежит в этом окружении, и запускать именно его по полному пути, видимо. Хотя это тоже не совсем правильно, но я не силён в виртуальных окружениях. А текущий каталог должен быть при этом такой, чтобы там можно было видеть `lib1` эти ваши.

Comment: os.system('cd ../venv/Scripts & start activate.bat & start M:\Ярлыки\PythonLiveTikTok\test\\test1.py') выполняется без ошибок, но: открывается консоль с уже активным venv, открывается на миллисекунду некая консоль c названием С:\Windows\py.exe и сразу же закрывается

Comment: Не, я предлагаю как-то так: `os.system('cd M:\Ярлыки\PythonLiveTikTok\test & start  ../venv/Scripts/python3.exe test1.py')` только пропишите полный путь до `python3`, а не относительный.

Comment: АААА! Спасибо большое! Это работает! Жаль что нельзя использовать относительные пути для переноса программы на другие пк и системы

Comment: На другие системы лучше бы через контейнеры `Docker` например переносить. Всё-таки скрипты питона не очень переносимая штука, к сожалению )  А так то возможно достаточно прописать правильный путь к `python3.exe` в `PATH`, но почему он сам при активации не прописывается, я не очень понимаю. Виртуальные окружения вообще какие-то мудрёные.

Comment: А ещё есть ли возможность открывать это не через командную строку а в IDE? Кстати можно указать короче os.system('start  M:\Ярлыки\PythonLiveTikTok\\venv\Scripts\python.exe test1.py')

Comment: Ну если так работает, то ок. Возможно, если вы уже в том каталоге, где лежат нужные библиотеки, то `cd` и не нужен. Либо `test1.py` библиотеки и так заберёт нормально если они в его каталоге лежат. Я не помню точно. А так то если вы в `IDE` запускаете, то просто выберите там нужное окружение питона, да и всё.

Comment: os.system('start ..\\venv\Scripts\python.exe test1.py') это тоже работает

Comment: чтобы вывод был в консоли IDE то нужно убрать start в os.system('start ..\\venv\Scripts\python.exe test1.py') Вопросов больше нет, ещё раз спасибо @CrazyElf .  Нужно ли тут как-то закрывать решенные вопросы?

Comment: Варианта два: 1) Дать самому ответ на свой вопрос 2) Удалить вопрос. Если считаете, что кому-то ещё это может помочь, то лучше вариант 1)

Comment: Вообще не понятно, зачем питоновские скрипты из питоновского скрипта таким образом через os.system запускать. Проще в скриптах код обернуть в функции, в основном скрипте импортировать и запускать эти функции в потоках.

Comment: тоже вариант...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы запустить оба файла с помощью виртуального окружения а не просто python нужно указать os.system('start ..\venv\Scripts\python.exe test1.py') и аналогично для второго файла, если результат нужно выводить в IDE а не в консоль тогда os.system('..\venv\Scripts\python.exe test1.py'). Вместо относительного пути до интерпретатора python можно использовать абсолютный.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вы как-то совсем уж короткий ответ дали и не на тот вопрос, который задавали изначально )